# Wait for an async function to end before executing another

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently working on some project. I need to add an item to a database and after doing that, executing another request to get the item I just added. Of course, everything must be non-blocking and the user needs to be able to still use the application while these operations execute in background.

Here is the code I use :

```
await AddItem(new Item(...params here ...);
return new ItemAdded(await GetItem(id));
```

I'd like to wait for `AddItem` to be executed before calling `GetItem(id)`, cause I need the item to be added in the database before getting it. However, it seems than this is not the case.

I tried to put debug message inside of the `GetItem` and `AddItem` functions and the message at the beginning of `GetItem` displays before the message at the end of `AddItem`.

How can I make sure to wait the end of `AddItem` while not blocking the user ?

**EDIT**

AddItem

```
public Task<Item> AddItem(Item item) { 
    return Task.Run(() => { 
        var param = ... params ... 
        _client.Post<string>("/item", param); 
        return item; 
    }); 
}
```

GetItem

```
public Task<Item> GetItem(Guid id)
{
    return Task.Run(() => _client.Get<Item>("/item/" + id));
}
```

Post

```
public async Task<T> Post<T>(string path, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_apiUrl + path, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
}
```

Comment: @mybirthname making the calls async does not necessarily make them concurrent. In fact, in the example above, they are already sequential.

Comment: The code should already do what you describe, can you explain why you're asking? `await AddItem` should not continue executing the current method until `AddItem` has completed. You probably need to post the code inside `AddItem`.

Comment: In the example you've provided, `AddItem` will complete before `GetItem` is invoked. If this isn't the behaviour you're seeing, you need to share more code.

Comment: Here is the AddItem code :

    public Task<Item> AddItem(Item item)
    {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var param = ... params ...
                _client.Post<string>("/item", param);
                return item;
            });
        }

Comment: @Pictar share the full revelant code *in the question*.

Comment: @AntP Could you share GetItem too?

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I added the GetItem and the Post function too. I think I understand the task problem here but I don't see how I can change it so it keeps the same behavior.

Comment: @Egorikas The `Task.Run` isn't *helping* anything, but it's not hurting anything either (beyond making the code a bit slower for no benefit).  The `Task` it returns is awaited, so the code won't continue on before it ends.

Comment: The problem is that the action passed to `Task.Run` itself doesn't await the async code it calls, so even though the task is awaited, it completes before it's "done." You should not need `Task.Run` at all - just await `Post` directly.

Comment: @AntP No need to `await` it, just `return` it.

Comment: @Servy `AddItem` doesn't return the result of the `Post` call though (for some reason). `GetItem` could return the task directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your AddItem method.
You should await for the post method. When you don't await for it, it still performs, but your code doesn't wait for it finishing and keeps going, due to this behaviour GetItem works faster than AddItem

```
public Task<Item> AddItem(Item item) { 
return Task.Run(async () => { 
    var param = ... params ... 
    await _client.Post<string>("/item", param); 
    return item; 
});
```

But I suppose that the better way to perform this

```
public async Task<Item> AddItem(Item item) { 
    var param = ... params ... 
    await _client.Post<string>("/item", param); 
    return item; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to await for the result from the post like this:

```
await _client.Post<string>("/item", param);
```

Otherwise the execution will continue to the next line which simply returns the item you passed in which then returns to `await AddItem(new Item(...params here ...);` and at this point that call has been satisfied and completed. Therefore, the execution will go to the next line which is:

```
return new ItemAdded(await GetItem(id));
```

But clearly the item may not have been added because you called post and returned right away without waiting for it to complete. MAY is the keyword here. In some instances by the time you call ItemAdded, it may have been added.